# Memory management with Java (how to use the data segment?)

Tags: java

I have very large data structures that I define as static fields in a class. I think they get pushed into the heap because my code fails with that error message (heap memory exceeded). Now, I think I recall there to be a memory segment besides heap and stack that is much larger, called data. Is it possible for me to push the variables in that segment? If so, how is this accomplished? I can't afford to increase the heap size because my program will be used by others.

Comment: All objects in Java are on the heap. You're exceeding *your available memory*. The Data segment has nothing to do with this (and no, it's not "much larger" or anything you can use - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you could really possibly mean is the *disk* -- actually writing things to files.